# A-Frame 0.3.0 not loading OBJs correctly - works in 0.2.0

Tags: three.js, aframe

When I updated scenes to use A-Frame 0.3.0, my OBJs no longer load correctly.

After changing the UVs on some models to not be negative (something which is legal OBJ) they started working in Firefox, but show up as white in Chrome and Safari. Chrome and Safari also ignore any direct color assignments -- "color: red" for instance. I'm not using any MTL files - just the geometry.

Before I go down the long road of hand editing OBJs until stuff works - were there any changes to A-Frame for 0.3.0 or in three.js that might be biting me? Like: no longer liking exponent notation in the OBJs? Needing to have something specific in the header? etc.

thanks,

Comment: If it's related to trying to use material component next to OBJ, there's some bugs with component ordering there. Try swapping obj-model and material components order in HTML.

Comment: Not trying to use the material component as far as I know. Trying to add more lines to the comment, but when I hit return the dialog exits :/

Comment: https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/smsinger-test/aframe/tests/obj_loader/v020/index.html     https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/smsinger-test/aframe/tests/obj_loader/v030/index.html

Comment: It seems you are using the material component. Try putting it before obj-model

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I thought you were referring to an MTL file. Sorry, it's been one of those days. I'll try that when I'm back at a computer. If that does it, then I'm hopeful it will solve other problems I've seen. Thanks!

Comment: you were right it was the ordering of the material and obj components. For some reason 0.2.0 was fine with it across the board and firefox is fine with it in 0.3.0  Those inconsistencies are always the trickiest to track down; thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As @ngokevin pointed out in his comment, swapping the order of my obj-model and material components fixed the issue.

```
<a-entity  obj-model="obj: #box_GEO" material=" color: lightblue; src: #ground_LM"></a-entity>
```

needed to be:

```
<a-entity  material=" color: lightblue; src: #ground_LM" obj-model="obj: #box_GEO"></a-entity>
```

Not sure what changed between versions 0.2.0 and 0.3.0, or why Firefox was more forgiving but I'm not stuck anymore.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Though it in fact does now work correctly in Chrome and Safari, now everything shows up all white in Firefox -- the situation just reversed itself :\ . Updating, restarting, rebooting, lunch, then make tests - things are bound to improve :)

Comment: It's a bug, we have a few filed for it. Will try to get around to fixing, or putting guidance in the issues to fix.

Comment: thanks - I'll stop scratching my head and get back to work :)